# How do you use multiple controllers in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I'm new to CodeIgniter and I've just gone through some of their user guide to help me understand how to do multiple controllers.

I have figured out how to load multiple pages using one of their examples. This is my default controller, called Site.php:

```
class Site extends CI_Controller {

public function index($page = 'home') {
    if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/'.$page.'.php')) {
        // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
        show_404();
    }

    $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

    $this->load->view('header', $data);
    $this->load->view($page, $data);
    $this->load->view('footer', $data);

    }
}
```

This all works well and good with my routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'site';
$route['(:any)'] = 'site/index/$1';
```

I have a few views that do load correctly when I go to `localhost/website/index.php/about`, for example.

---

Now, to further learn about controllers and URI routing. I created a new controller, `application/controllers/MyController.php` and it is coded as such:

```
class MyController extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('my_controller');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

The thing is, I don't know how to access this page.
I understand that the default URI pattern is `example.com/class/function/id/` but I have tried `localhost/website/mycontroller` and it doesn't work. Apache returns 404. I've tried many manipulations of this, even going as stupid as typing `localhost/website/index.php/mycontroller` but of course that doesn't work.

**What is the correct way to use multiple controllers? What have I done wrong here? Please assist me in my learning, thank you!**

<sub>(Also, this is my first proper question on StackOverflow, if I've done anything wrong or formatted something incorrectly, please let me know!)</sub>

Comment: `$route['(:any)'] = 'site/index/$1';` remove this from your routes.php and everything will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this rule:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'site/index/$1';
```

intercepts **everything**... and passes it to the `Site` controller, as an argument to the `index` method. So if you call:

```
/mycontroller
```

it will actually map to:

```
/site/index/mycontroller
```

The routing happens before the app even looks at the controllers, and the routing rules are considered in order they are written.

Thus you need to put this rule at the very bottom of your rule list in order to let the other rules work. So by adding this in front:

```
$route['mycontroller'] = 'mycontroller';
$route['(:any)'] = 'site/index/$1';
```

it should work fine (although sligthly unusual approach, but so is your global `any` rule) as it will first check if the URL requested was `/mycontroller` and if so, it will call `myController`; otherwise it will behave like it used to with your `Site` controller.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Including the `mycontroller` route worked, though I have a question about the `any`route. You say it is unusual, however there's no way for me to access the pages generated in my `Site` controller if I don't have the `any` route. Is this a black-and-white thing, where I should choose explicitly between using multiple controllers, or only one controller for all pages? What is the best way to approach this? (Should I ask this in another question?)

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, it is sort of black or white here. Depends on your site structure, you can opt for each. I've shown you how to proceed with one controller, and basically whitelisting all the other controllers. You can also avoid using `any` route and map only those method (or views, in your case) that actually exist... so for `about`, you'd write: `$route['about'] = 'site/index/about';` and that way you won't have to fight against the `any` route and your other controllers will work normally.

Comment: If what I wrote in the comment above is hard to read or makes no sense, maybe it's better to write a new question about it.

Comment: Nope, what you've provided not only makes sense, but it actually enabled me to use both multiple controllers _and_ the single controller method. With all three route lines, `default_controller`, `mycontroller` and `any` I am able to access every page at `localhost/website/index.php/[home,about,mycontroller]` which is very cool. You've been a great help, thank you. I will eventually decide which site structure I will opt for.

Comment: Perfect!!! I'm glad I could help. The next thing is probably to [get rid of that `index.php`](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html).

Comment: Haha, you're absolutely right. There appears to be a ton of information about editing the htaccess file so in the unlikely event I run into any problems, I'll make another question.

Comment: Yup, it used to be one of the hottest issues back when CI became popular.

Answer (score 1):

You are routing everything to your Site controller with the routing rule:

`$route['(:any)'] = 'site/index/$1';`

With such a catch-all routing rule you will never reach other controllers as for example your Mycontroller.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is your calling method
In your case if you don't have mod_rewrite on you should try

```
localhost/website/index.php/mycontroller
```

if you are able to activate mod_rewrite you can add in your .htaccess the following lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

after that you can call your controller like you tried before

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am running WAMP so I have control over the rewrite module. I deactivated it and tried your first suggestion, it didn't work.

Which .htaccess file do you refer to? The one in my /application/ folder? Currently, they all have some kind of XML, two sets of <ifmodule> tags. Do I append what you provided to the end of this file? I'm sorry, I haven't worked with .htaccess files before!

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the routing problem here... it's not about removing the `index.php` part from the URL...

Comment: the first suggestion of mine should route you to the site/index controller (like other suggested here)
if you still get a 404 - i'm not sure - did you delete your site Controller?

Comment: Shomz you are totally wrong - because he wrote explicitly he gets an 404
if the url looks like `localhost/website/mycontroller`

if apache return an 404 - you dont have a routing problem in ci because ci isn 't involved here

Comment: You see what happens when the view isn't found? CI throws a 404! I'm pretty sure this happens from CI, not Apache. So in your case, it would enter the Site controller, look for `views/index.php/mycontroller.php`, won't find it, and throw 404.

Comment: yeah he wrote apache did - this is a bit of a difference
@Psymøn did you get an error like `The requested URL /website/mycontroller/ was not found on this server.` or did you get a message from CI like `404 Page Not Found` in a well formatted page

Comment: OP said it works with `about`, so it's a missing view thing, but OP wants to get inside a whole other controller here, which is blocked by the routing he uses. Yes, good point on the 404 error message.

Comment: @Shomz After applying your solution, when trying to access `localhost/website/index.php/` it automatically loads `home` which is correct, however I get a CI 404 when trying to acess `localhost/website/index.php/about` or even `index.php/home`. Earlier, I was getting Apache 404s _and_ CI 404s depending on which method I attempted. `localhost/website/mycontroller/` got an Apache 404 and `localhost/website/index.php/mycontroller/` got a CI 404. That was before Shomz's fix.

Comment: sintakonte's code is used for removing the `index.php` part of the URL, which is why you were getting Apache's 404s. Try just `/about` or `/home`. Make sure you set the index page in config to blank (if it's not).