# codeigniter how to create multiple controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter, controllers

I am new to codeigniter and I want to make my program with multiple controllers. Can someone give me a link or a video link of a tutorial on how to make this possible or can someone here teach me?  They always tell me to use h m v c but i don't think I can use h m v c yet.

Comment: you can find good tutorials on http://tutorialcodeigniter.com/

Comment: also refer this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073491/how-do-you-use-multiple-controllers-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

The information in https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/tutorial/index.html was most helpful to me.

Basically:

Create a class 
Use the config/routes.php file to assign you class methods to a route.  For a usual Create, Read, Update and Delete functions the routes might look like this:

```
    $route['equipments/create'] = 'equipments/create';
    $route['equipments/update/(:any)'] = 'equipments/update/$1';
    $route['equipments/view/(:any)'] = 'equipments/view/$1';
    $route['equipments'] = 'equipments';
```

The left hand side is the url format and the right hand side is the class (equipments) and methods (create,update, etc).  The '$1' after the slash is the parameters for the class.