# How to use multiple controllers and model in codeigniter 3.1.4?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am very new to codeigniter and i am using the version 3.1.4. 
I have 2 users in my system and i wanted to use 2 different controllers in the same system, since i felt that using one single controller will have too many functions in it.

what i found as solution was similar to these: [How do you use multiple controllers in CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073491/how-do-you-use-multiple-controllers-in-codeigniter)

i dont find any  $route['(:any)']  in my routes file.

**Please help me solve this with every step since i am very new. 
I want to know how to route it and how to call the function (in both the controllers) in a view page as well as model.**

Also i need help in using 2 models.(for that i think i just need to mention the model name while calling the fucntion in model)need advice.

Comment: CodeIgniter has a tutorial in its documentation, use it: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use routing for all user to redirect to same controller with the routing rule:

$route['users/(:any)'] = "users/index/$1";

for example-
I have two user manager and admin

http://localhost/project/users/manager/create

http://localhost/project/users/admin/create

both request redirect to users/index and now you can get value of the function using

$func = $this->uri->segment(3, 'list');

$user_type = $this->uri->segment(2, 0);

Now use switch case for call a function

switch ($func) {

```
        case 'create':

            $this->create($user_type);

            return;

        default:

            $this->view($user_type);

            return;

    }
```